# interrupting boost::asio::async_receive_from from another thread

Tags: c++, windows, boost-asio

I am reading multicast input using `async_receive_from`. So the idea is that when I detect a gap, I will notify another helper thread to request/get the gap filling messages. While this is in the works the main thread will continue to receive and queue any incoming messages. This part I can implement. The other thread can use waitforsingleobject and I can pass it the details through shared memory and notify an event to wake it up.

But once it completes it task, how do I get the helper thread to interrupt the `async_receive_from` in the initiating thread? And when it comes up out of the the read it knows who interrupted so it will then know what to do next?

Comment: Your design sounds needlessly complex, to get some better answers you should clarify why you are using a helper thread and shared memory. Both of these concepts are somewhat strange when using asio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using shared memory between threads?

That aside, the mechanism you should use for executing something in the context of the `io_service` which is managing the socket is `post()`. You can post any arbitrary event to the io_service, and it will execute in that context. Quite easy really... Because you are calling `async_receive_from`, it's not blocking, i.e. the io_service can dispatch other events, which is why the `post` will work.

Comment: I just tried that and it looks like the async_receive_from doesn't get serviced until the posted(dispatched) function completes. Although the app continues after the post is initiated and the asyn_receive_from is entered, it seems blocked until the dispatched function completes. Basically, I need the posting function and the posted function to run concurrently and unblocked.

Comment: Nim please see my comment for your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @Al Kurlansky, I don't get what you are talking about, basically you've got a thread calling run on presumably the `datagram_socket_service`? You've got a another thread, from which you `post` a handler to execute. Once you've posted the handler, the io service will execute that handler when possible. Now if you have an `async_receive_from` also in progress, this does not "block" as you think, it's asynchronous, i.e. the completion handler will get executed once a packet is successfully read. And while it's waiting for the packet, it will happily execute any other handlers i.e. ones you post

Comment: ... now if you post a handler to the io service, and it's executing the completion handler for `async_receive_from`, then that's a different issue. If you're code takes a long time in that handler, then the second thread which is posting will be "blocked". If this is the case, you need to ensure that you take the least amount of time possible...